# how to pass a ofstream to a function and save it into a member variable

Tags: c++, reference, ofstream

I have this code:

```
class myclass
{
       ofstream &myfile;
    public:
       void init(ofstream &file)
       {
              myfile=file;
       }
       void say(int x)
       {
          myfile<<x;
       }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
     Error  5   error C2280: 'std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator =(const std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
```

on this line:

```
  myfile=file;
```

how can I fix it? Please note that I want a solution that I should not change this line:

```
 myfile<<x;
```

Comment: Do you really want to store just a reference to `file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::ofstream` doesn't have a copy assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/).  You have to [`move`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/operator=/) it or [`swap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/swap/).

Comment: can you please provide a sample code to show how to move or swap it?

Comment: @mans you would do `myFile = move(file);`.  This isn't a great solution though, taking in the `ofstream` as an argument to `say` or taking it in and initializing it in the constructor is my cleaner than dealing with ownership.

Comment: @mans if you do decide to do it this way, it might make more sense to have init take in an rvalue instead of an lvalue: `void init(ofstream && file)`

Answer (score 0):

References have to be initialized at the point of definition of the class. So you have to create a constructor and initialize `myfile` using the initializer list:

```
class myclass {
    ofstream& myfile;
public:
    myclass(std::ofstream& file) : myfile(file) { }

    void say(int x) {
        myfile << x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference types (like `ofstream&`) must be bound at initialization time, and once bound, it cannot be rebound to something else. I would suggest the following code which allows you to rebind:

```
class myclass {
  ofstream* myfile = nullptr;
public:
  void init(ofstream& file) {
    myfile = &file;
  }
  void say(int x) const {
    if (myfile) (*myfile) << x;
    else ...
  }
};
```